# React Native: react-native run-android is not starting Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I am starting to build an Android application using React Native. But when I tried to run the application using "react-native run-android" command, it runs into a problem. This is what I have done so far.

I installed the react-native command line running the following commands

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then I created the react-native project running the following command.

```
react-native init {ProjectName}
```

At this point, I already have the Andriod Studio installed I have been doing the native Android development. So, I opened the Android Studio and started an emulator.

Then within the React Native project, I run the following command to start the project.

```
react-native run-android
```

Then I got the following error.

```
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 903 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_XL_API_30_2(AVD) - 11' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
29 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 27 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to start the app.
Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n com.testreactnative/com.testreactnative.MainActivity
```

In an attempt to fix that, I added the following environment user variables pointing to the right location.

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
ANDROID_HOME: C:\AndroidSDK
```

Then I tried running the command again. It is still throwing the same error. What's wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can start the emulator by `AVD manager` from Android Studion and then run that command again

Comment: I tried. It is still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You see this error in console that says `'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

This means that `adb` path is not added in `Environment Variables`

My `adb` path is = `C:\Users\karti\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

Find yours and add it to `Path` in `Environment Variables`

Comment: I added the adb path into the environment variables and it is still not working.